# How to Export Data from MySQL to Excel in Asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need exporting to **XLS file** Data from **MySQL** to **Excel** in Asp.net using C#.

I have tried this code, but if the user is the holder of multiple authorization, the response of page is error :

> ERROR [07001] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1
>   Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community]SQLBindParameter not used for all
>   parameters

On this line :

```
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Instead if the user is the holder of single authorization, the export to excel working correctly.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

The code is given below.

SQL Query for multiple authorization :

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_csv` WHERE iTES IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

**My code behind:**

```
using (OdbcConnection cn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        foreach (var co in colorList)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(co, co);

            using (OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "SqlExport.xls"));
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

                    string str = string.Empty;
                    foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        Response.Write(str + dtcol.ColumnName);
                        str = "\t";
                    }
                    Response.Write("\n");
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        str = "";
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
                            str = "\t";
                        }
                        Response.Write("\n");
                    }
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use XLS, it's obsolete since 2010 - over 7 years ago. Google Sheets won't even accept it unless you have a paying subscription. Use a library like EPPlus to generate a real XLSX file. It's as simple as `sheet.LoadFromDataTable(dt)`.

Comment: It looks like your SQL query has *many* parameters.  And in the code you're adding *one* parameter.  Seems like the error is telling you exactly that.

Comment: Check the [Web Application sample](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample).

Comment: From @beingpakistani : *I  found this video helpful, maybe it could help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcIkjudRORw *

Comment: As for your query, the `IN (...)` statement should contain as many items as there are parameters, not more or less. In SQL Server you could avoid the problem by using a TVP (ie parameter with list of values that appears as table) and join to it. If you don't want to use string concatenation, eg because you can't validate all parameters, try passing dummy values for the missing parameters

Comment: @David thanks for reply, but the SQL query tried in MySQL working correctly.

Comment: Another option is to insert the values into a temporary table and join with it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks but is Data MySQL and not SQL Server

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq: And how did you try it when it was "working correctly"?  Did you supply *all* of the parameters?  Show the actual information.  If we're supposed to just take your word for it that everything works then there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq the error says you didn't pass enough parameters. BTW  the ADO.NET [MySQLCommand expects *named* parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html). Perhaps the same applies to the ODBC driver? Why are you using the ODBC driver instead of ADO.NET's abstract classes or MySQL's classes anyway?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq which makes no difference *at all*. You are still using the ADO.NET classes to generate datatables. In fact, you are using the ODBC provider, not MySQL's ADO.NET provider (why?). The DataTable is the same class, no matter where it came from. You can use the `sheet.LoadFromDataTable(table)` command with any datatable

Comment: @David working correctly it means that the export has provided all the required data in sql query. But working if single authorization.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq: So... When you provide all of the necessary parameters it works, and when you don't provide all of the necessary parameters it doesn't work?  Strangely enough, that's *exactly* what the error message is telling you.  So what's the problem?  Why are you trying to make something work without the necessary parameters?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq did you leave parameter placeholders in your MySQL query? Did you use a parameterized query with MySQL or did you replace the placeholders with actual values. That's what the problem is about. Your query specifies 20 parameters. Did you pass 20 parameters in your code?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq the problem is the loop itself. The code loops over the colorlist and tries to create one sheet per entry. It adds one parameter at a time *and executes* the query. So the first time the command has only 1 parameter instead of 20, the second it would have 2 etc. Did you forget a closing bracket?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq the code should be ` foreach (var co in colorList)
        {cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(co, co);}` *only*.

Comment: Another issue, this code generates a CSV but says it's an Excel document. This will cause problems for spreadsheet programs that try to open it, including Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ERROR [07001] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters

The error is telling you that you're missing some parameters in the query.  Let's take a look at the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_csv` WHERE iTES IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

That's 20 parameters.  And here's where you add parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(co, co);
```

That's 1 parameter.  The query expects 20.  Now, it's not clear to me what this code is *intending* to do (what is an "authorization"?  what is a "color"?  etc.), but perhaps you meant to *add the parameters* in the loop and then execute the query *once*?  Something like this...

```
foreach (var co in colorList)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(co, co);
}

using (OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter())
{
    // continue using the query
```

You'll probably still want to put in some validation that the parameter count matches, since there's no guarantee that whatever `colorList` is has the exact number of parameters the query needs.  But at the very least this seems closer to the intent of adding multiple parameters to a single query.

If, on the other hand, you are intending to execute the query in a loop over whatever `colorList` is, then in each iteration of that loop you're going to want to add all of the necessary parameters.  (And probably clear the existing ones from the previous iteration.  Honestly, each iteration should probably make its own `OdbcCommand` object in that case.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the loop itself. The code loops over the colorlist and tries to create one sheet per entry. It adds one parameter at a time and executes the query. So the first time the command has only 1 parameter instead of 20, the second it would have 2 etc.

The loop should be:

```
foreach (var co in colorList)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(co, co);
}
```

Another problem is that the code isn't generating an Excel file at all. It generates a delimited text file and tries to "fake it" by using an Excel extension and content type. Needless to say, this causes problems, especially with Excel. Firewalls and antivirus programs may also take exception to the fake content type.

Excel itself will realize this isn't a real Excel file and try to **import the text** using the system locale's settings for decimal and list separators. This can fail if the locale is different from the server's locale.

The solution to this is to create a real Excel file with EPPlus. This generates a real `xlsx` file without requiring Excel on the server. It results in a smaller file too, as `xlsx` is just a bunch of zipped xml files.

Generating an actual Excel file using your data is as simple as:

```
sda.Fill(dt);
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //Create the worksheet
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

    /Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
    //Write it back to the client
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

That's it. Generating the sheet is a single line. The final three lines send the response to the browser using the correct headers.

This [Web Application sample](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) expands on this to format the generated sheet.

**UPDATE**

You might be able to get rid of the DataAdapter too. You can load a DataTable directly from an IDataReader. Data adapters were introduced as ... adapters between Windows forms and grids on the one side, tables on the other. They aren't required to work with DataTable objects. In fact, they went out of favour quite a while ago with the introduction of ORMs like EF and microORMs like Dapper.

Your code could be simplified to :

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
{
    foreach (var co in colorList)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(co, co);
    }
    using(var reader=cmd.ExecuteReader())
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        dt.Load(reader);
    }
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

        /Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        //Write it back to the client
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());         
    }
}
```

**Even simpler with Dapper**

[Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) works with MySQL and allows you to pass a list of parameters to a query. You could convert your data logic to this:

```
using(var cn=new MySqlConnection(..))
using(var reader=cn.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM `tbl_csv` WHERE iTES IN @cols",new {cols=colorList}))
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    dt.Load(reader);
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
         //Same as before
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the Dapper method. Worked exactly as advertised.